# showing a very simple image in OpenCV

Tags: c, opencv

I'm very new to OpenCV and I have a very very simple code for making a white image and showing it:

```
IplImage* track=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame1),IPL_DEPTH_8U,3);
cvSet(track,cvScalar(255,255,255));
cvShowImage("Result",track);
```

when I run it, I get this error:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (udata<(uchar*)ptr && ((uchar*)ptr-udata)<=(ptrdiff_t)(sizeof(void*)+16)) in unknown function, file ........\ocv\opencv\src\cxcore\cxalloc.cpp, line 76

Why does this happen?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Can you post the declaration of `frame1`?

Comment: offtop: i advise you to use cvMat

Answer (score 1):

Just check you frame1 and make sure it is not NULL .

Comment: No, it's not. I checked it.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the error is from the line

```
cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame1),IPL_DEPTH_8U,3);
```

To verify where the error comes from, try cvSize(320,240) instead of cvGetSize(frame1). If it works at that point, check the size of frame1 (we can help you more if you post the code fro declaring and initializing frame1).

Comment: I used this: CvCapture* video= cvCreateFileCapture("D:\\A1.avi");
 IplImage* frame1 = cvQueryFrame(video); But it's so strange, when I use cvSize(320,240) as you said, and want to show both "frame1" and "track" in separate windows, that's OK, there is no problem. But when I use cvGetSize(frame1), the error appears again.

Comment: cvQueryFrame documentation says "The returned image should not be released or modified by the user". You are not doing that here, but may be there is a problem with using the accessor functions too.
I checked my code used for video analysis, and found that I always cloned the image first. Another possibility is cvSize(frame1->width, frame1->height).